# How to drop an existing connection on Ubuntu 20.04 server?

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I executed the following command to ban them. But it didn't work. It only works when there is a new connection from that IP.

`sudo ufw insert 1 deny from 46.1.67.244 to any && sudo ufw reload`

status ufw: `Anywhere                   DENY        46.1.67.244`

I have a service that is always listening on port A
The connection from that ip is always kept, it just loses the connection when I stop the service.
How can I drop this current connection without stopping the service?

Comment: We need the output of:

```ufw status verbose```

to see what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

UFW is just a front end for iptables. Typically, the generated rule set has as RELATED,ESTABLISHED ACCEPT rule early in the INPUT chain. If you add a specific DROP rule before that generic rule, the packets should be intercepted and dropped.

In this example, I will add a rule and drop subsequent packets from 192.168.111.122 to my main test server at 192.168.111.132. For demonstration, I have a very simple iptables rule set:

```
$ sudo iptables -xvnL
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       2      100 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 LOG        tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "IINVALID:"
       0        0 DROP       tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
       0        0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 ctstate NEW LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "NEW TCP no SYN:"
       0        0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 ctstate NEW
     159    11289 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       1       52 ACCEPT     tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

And am currently connected via SSH from 2 computers:

```
$ who
doug     pts/0        2023-01-05 15:55 (192.168.111.1)
doug     pts/1        2023-01-05 15:56 (192.168.111.122)
```

Now add the new rule to DROP packets from 192.168.111.122:

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT 2 -s 192.168.111.122 -i br0 -j DROP
```

The SSH session terminates (might take a while).

```
$ client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset
```

And packets are being dropped:

```
$ sudo iptables -xvnL
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
      26     2926 DROP       all  --  br0    *       192.168.111.122      0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 LOG        tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "IINVALID:"
       0        0 DROP       tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
       0        0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 ctstate NEW LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "NEW TCP no SYN:"
       0        0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 ctstate NEW
     100     8437 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       1       52 ACCEPT     tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Note that the session still shows as logged in, but it will eventually be deleted:

```
$ who
doug     pts/0        2023-01-05 15:55 (192.168.111.1)
doug     pts/1        2023-01-05 15:56 (192.168.111.122)
```

Comment: I tried, it just clears from list connect. It does not disconnect. I had to stop the service to get it to disconnect!

Comment: To try to understand why it didn't work, we would have to review your UFW generated iptables rules. UFW generated iptables rule sets are difficult to read/follow.

Comment: Okay, wrote a new answer.